# Using LSTM to find mode of a sequence

Tags: python, lstm, keras

I trained an LSTM network to predict the mode of a sequence of real numbers. I found the performance to be poor. Initially, I thought this is a fairly easy objective and LSTM networks would perform very well.

A training sample: X - [1,4,3,4,4,2] Y - [4]

I used keras to implement LSTM, the train data comprised of 20000 sequences with their mode as target

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=special_value, input_shape=(max_seq_len, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(32,activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mse')
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working so I won't attempt to answer the question. Just two thoughts: 1) I think that your model is *way* too complex for your very simple task. Two LSTM networks with 32 units each one after another for a single sequence of length ~6 seems like an overkill. It could lead to overfitting; keep that in mind. 2) I think your task is pretty weird for a NN to achieve, because the mode requires keeping track of the frequency of each element, something a NN doesn't do inherently. If you tried to find the mean or the median, it I agree with you that it would be trivial...

Comment: @Djib2011 Thank you for the response. 1) The sequences in my training set are of length more than 1000. The sample I provided was only to give a notion about the dataset. 2) LSTM networks are widely used in applications in which current observation is affected by past observations. So I thought an LSTM model could take into account the most repeating value.

Comment: Regarding (2): That is true, but I don't see this being the case in your application. For example, if your input is `[1,4,3,4,4,2]` or `[1,2,3,4,4,4]` or `[4,4,4,3,2,1]` the mode doesn't change. In other words, your data isn't autocorrelated, which is one of the main thing LSTMs exploit. For example imagine the temperature measurements that are taken every hour. They can't change dramatically. Regarding your data this means that the temp for one hour is dependent on its previous hour(s). So if you want to predict the temp now, the previous hour is more important than a temp 20 hours back.